# SQL - if-statement in function

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I have some trouble with an if-statement in my function.
I'm getting

```
ERROR: Syntaxfehler bei »if«
SQL Status:42601
Zeichen:78
```

I'm trying to get the data between two dates. If there is no date-Input, I want to get all the data. 
The code looks like this

```
create or replace function datacut(DATE, DATE)
returns record AS $$
if $1 = ''
then
select * from hist_point;
else
SELECT *
from hist_point h
Where h.valid_from < $2 AND h.valid_from >= $1;
end if;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This is just a prototyp for some other functions.

Any sort of tip, hint or help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changine this Where h.valid_from < $2 AND h.valid_from >= $1;   to Where h.valid_from BETWEEN $1 AND $2

Comment: I am not postgresql guy, but does it mandatory to write RETURN statement at end of function?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL syntax, function and parameter definitions in that SQL dialect, but I imagine the SQL can be combined into one SELECT with something like  `Where ($1 = '') OR ( h.valid_from < $2 AND h.valid_from >= $1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function datacut(DATE, DATE)
    returns record AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE  
BEGIN 
        IF $1 = '' then
            select * from hist_point;
        else
            SELECT * from hist_point h where h.valid_from < $2 AND h.valid_from >= $1;
        end if;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```